# How to properly create a python package and use it in another project

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I have a new project with following folder architecture.

[image]

PineconeClient is a class with 3 methods

inside indexes folder init.py looks like this:

```
"""Wrappers on top of vector stores."""
from e61indexingclient.indexes.PineconeClient import (CreateIndex, DeleteIndex, IndexAllDocumentsFromBlobStorage)


__all__ = [
    "PineconeClient",
    "CreateIndex",
    "DeleteIndex",
    "IndexAllDocumentsFromBlobStorage"  
]
```

in the root the init folder looks like this too:

```
"""Main entrypoint into package."""

from importlib import metadata
from typing import Optional

try:
    __version__ = metadata.version(__package__)
except metadata.PackageNotFoundError:
    # Case where package metadata is not available.
    __version__ = ""
del metadata  # optional, avoids polluting the results of dir(__package__)

verbose: bool = False
debug: bool = False

__all__ = [
    "PineconeClient",
    "CreateIndex",
    "DeleteIndex",
    "IndexAllDocumentsFromBlobStorage"
]
```

With poetry build I can generate a whl file.

However here comes the issue

In the other project, I try to install the package like this:

```
pip install pathtowhlfile
```

The install works fine.

Whats the issue then?

if I do `import e61indexingclient` its not recognized
If I do `from e61indexingclient.indexes.Pineconeclient import CreateIndex, DeleteIndex` its also not recognized

What am I doing wrong?

pyproject.toml file

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "e61indexingclient"
version = "0.0.5"
description = ""
authors = ["x"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
langchain = "^0.0.232"
openai = "^0.27.8"
pinecone-client = "^2.2.2"
azure-storage-blob = "^12.17.0"
azure-identity = "^1.13.0"
azure-ai-textanalytics = "^5.3.0"
azure-core = "^1.28.0"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

My whl files look like this:
[image]

I use poetry build to generate whl files

Comment: Could you please provide the content structure of your wheel file, the relevant parts of your pyproject.toml file, and the distribution command you used?

Comment: see my edited question, let me know if you need more info

Comment: Can you share the output from `pip show e61indexingclient`. This should give you the location of the package. I would also like to see the file structure of the folder there the package is installed aka. `<path given by location>/e61indexingclient`
Just to confirm that the package is install correctly 

Comment: I see this location: Location: c:\users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages  -> which s weird because the project where  I installed its using venv not conda. so I think the issue is in  the virtual environments not on the package itself?

Comment: @LuisValencia Sorry for the delayed response. In fact, you didn't respond to my solution or mention me, so I didn't get notified. I've created [this](https://github.com/AlirezaRoshanzamir/stackoverflow-76691557) GitHub repository for your problem. Could you please test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `from e61indexingclient.indexes.Pineconeclient import CreateIndex, DeleteIndex` is not working is because you should use `PineconeClient` (with a capital 'C') instead of `Pineconeclient`.

However, the `import e61indexingclient` statement works correctly without any issues. Nevertheless, you cannot use something similar to `e61indexingclient.CreateIndex` because your root `__init__.py` file does not import them. You can only export the variables that are accessible in the module using the `__all__` attribute. Therefore, you should modify your root `__init__.py` file as follows:

```
"""Main entrypoint into package."""

from importlib import metadata
from typing import Optional

from .indexes import PineconeClient, CreateIndex, DeleteIndex, IndexAllDocumentsFromBlobStorage

try:
    __version__ = metadata.version(__package__)
except metadata.PackageNotFoundError:
    # Case where package metadata is not available.
    __version__ = ""
del metadata  # optional, avoids polluting the results of dir(__package__)

verbose: bool = False
debug: bool = False

__all__ = [
    "PineconeClient",
    "CreateIndex",
    "DeleteIndex",
    "IndexAllDocumentsFromBlobStorage"
]
```

In the `e61indexingclient/indexes/__init__.py` file, you should also import the `PineconeClient` (hence, there exists a `PineconeClient` variable inside the module) so you can explicitly export it:

```
from e61indexingclient.indexes import PineconeClient
...
```

I've created [this](https://github.com/AlirezaRoshanzamir/stackoverflow-76691557) repository for your problem. You can simply run the mentioned commands and test the solution.

I also recommend using `from .foo import Foo as Foo` for explicit exports instead of relying on the `__all__` variable. This approach ensures clarity and allows you to easily identify the reason if variable names change or if you forget to import a variable for explicit exporting. Please refer to the `__init__.py` files of two well-known Python libraries [Click](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/main/src/click/__init__.py) or [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/__init__.py), for examples.

Comment: still doesnt work, and when I say it doesnt work, I meant VScode intellisense doesnt recognize the imported modules

Comment: @LuisValencia I have tested it. Please create a new virtual environment and perform the testing within it. You can verify your installation by inspecting the `{venv-directory}/lib/python{python-version}/site-packages/e61indexingclient` directory and examining the contents of the `__init__.py` files within it.

Comment: @LuisValencia I've updated my solution. Please try it again.

Comment: thanks! for some reason when I open VS COde the existing environment on the .venv folder was not selected, so I created a new one and it works